# Create RMI stubs

Tags: rmi, netbeans-6.9

I am using Netbeans 6.9.1. I want to create a stub for my server class. I got stuck there. Browsing through several StackOverflow forums, i found varied answers, which ranged from "no need of creating a stub" to "modify the build.xml". I tried the latter, but it did not work. Can someone please tell me what I should do? Is there any plugin of some sort that I can use? (I did not find any) 
http://netbeans.org/projects/rmi/  shows a 404 error. :(

Vikram.

Comment: and i tried to create it through terminal, using rmic command. But for some reason, it says class not found. Do I have to set the classpath? (something i picked up from The Complete Reference Java)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a stub for my server
>   class.

Why? Stubs haven't been needed since 1.5 came out, many years ago now.